# DB2: Getting [IBM][CLI Driver] SQLSTATE=58004 SQLCODE=-1042

Tags: python, db2, jupyter-notebook

I am new to IBM DB2 world and trying to establish a connection with DB2 using Jupyter notebook:

```
import ibm_db

try:
    ibm_db.pconnect("DATABASE=DB2;HOSTNAME=hostname;PORT=60000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=user;PWD=password;", "", "")
    print("Connected to DB")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

But getting:

```
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004 SQLCODE=-1042
```

Any suggestions here?

Edit:

Got the solution for the issue. Posting it here so someone might be helped:

Add `AUTHENTICATION=SERVER` in the `ibm_db.pconnect` string.

Comment: If is better to add an answer to your own question rather that do that as an edit.

Comment: @PaulVernon Thanks for the correction. I did it that way now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `AUTHENTICATION=SERVER` in the `ibm_db.pconnect` string.

Comment: Just in case this helps anybody: I could only get it to work with python 3.6, ibm_db 3.1.0 (not 3.1.1), AND ATHENTICATION=SERVER. I don't think you can install ibm_db 3.1.0 on later versions of python (I only tried python 3.10 but it didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

If you're code works on Linux but fails on Windows and you are using SQLAlchemy, this might also help:

> You may be experiencing a known defect that affects some Microsoft Windows configurations.
>
> Use pip show ibm_db to find the "Location:" of your site-packages
> directory.
>
> Suppose for example, that directory is c:\python\lib\site-packages
>
> Your installation directory will be different, but try to understand
> the idea.
>
> Then modify your PATH environment variable to append the following
> directory to the PATH:
>
> c:\python\lib\site-packages\clidriver\bin\amd64.VC12.CRT
>
> (that is, your site-packages path with \clidriver\bin\amd64.VC12.CRT
> appended to it )
>
> After modifying the PATH, you can retry the python ibm_db database
> connection.
>
> If you do not have permission to modify the PATH, you can also copy
> the contents (2 .DLL files) of that amd64.VC12.CRT directory , into
> another directory that you know will be already on the PATH when
> python runs.
>
> If you are encrypting your database connections with SSL/TLS, you
> sometimes also need to add a second directory to the PATH ( ...
> site-packages\clidriver\bin\icc64 ) .

From https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/599

Answer (score 0):

We were getting following error and it was due to AS400 storage get full.

```
SQL system error. (SQLSTATE 58004, SQLCODE -901)
```