Python will not connect to Db2: SQLCODE=-1042
I followed the advise given in the thread where the Python error below comes up if trying to connect to DB2 after installing ibm_db with pip:
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004  SQLCODE=-1042
The suggested two additions to my PATH are added at the beginning of my python script now before trying to connect:
sys.path.append('C:\HighmarkApps\Python3.12.2\Lib\site-packages\clidriver\bin\amd64.VC12.CRT')
sys.path.append('C:\HighmarkApps\Python3.12.2\Lib\site-packages\clidriver\bin\icc64')
While a number of users report that this solved their issue it did nothing for my case.
I have tried dozens of connect string combos (below is the latest) but none have allowed
a 'connection' to be made 'always' returning the above error message instead.
conn = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=basename;HOSTNAME=hostname;PORT=999;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=xxxxxxx;PWD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;","SECURITY=SSL;","SSLServerCertificate=C:\xxxxxxxxxxxx\Python3.12.2\Lib\site-packages\clidriver\cfg\DigiCertGlobalRootCA.arm")
Does anyone have any additional suggestions ??

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52608802/2834978

The connect syntax looks incorrect. Use a separate variable for the connection string. Format the long string for easy readability (for example, with a single property per line), call that variable for example conn_string. All of the settings should be inside that connection string, separated by ; and quoted correctly when there are spaces or special characters in path/file names, and the last character of the string before the closing quote should be ;". Your connect line should then look like conn = ibm_db.connect(conn_string, "", "").
